# What do we mean by log-scaling a plot?

Tags: logarithms, normal-distribution, transformation, data-analysis

So imagine we have the following plot, which is a histogram (but it works also for plotting functions, the question is the same!) of random samples from a normal distribution.

[image: hist]

Often I hear about log-scaling it. Using the computer (Python), I can set the scale to log and I get the following:

[image: hist2]

now of course if we take the logarithm of the normal distribution, we end up with a parabola. So looking at the second image, it does look like a parabola with negative coeffiecient (as it should be!) so my first idea was

> log-scaling means that we take each value $y(x)$ (or in general the whole function $y=y(x)$), we take its logarithm and we plot it against the same $x$'s.

However using Python, I tried this manually and it turns out it doesn't work. Then my second idea was:

> log-scaling means taking the log of both the input ($x$) and the output $(y(x)$ and plot $y(x)$ agains $x$.

Again, simply by trying we see it doesn't work.

Then asking on stackoverflow, I was told that

> what (supposedly) what the logscaling does, is to scale the axes, but NOT THE INPUT AND THE OUTPUT.

but then again what does that even mean?

To give a context: imagine I have a normal distribution, if I plot it I get a curve similar to the profile of picture one. If I take the logarithm of it, I should get a shifted negative parabola and then if I take the square root of it (restricting the values of $x$ so that $y(x)$ are all above the $x$ axis), I should get a straight line. Right?

So that is what I would like to do with my data. But if I try it comes out wrong, which means that log-scaling actually means something else. So then what does it mean?

Comment: "What does that even mean?" It means we change the grid lines, spacing out the ones close to $0$ and bunching together grid lines corresponding to higher values, but the data is plotted on the same points in the coordinate grid as before. The topmost column will still reach $650$.

Comment: @Arthur I'm sorry if I ask so many things but.. what do you mean by grid lines? And also, how can spacing the gridlines change the shape of the plot, if the data  is the same?

Comment: By grid lines I mean the vertical grid lines corresponding to constant $y$ values in the plane in which you draw your graph / histogram. But try to think about it this way: take your first plot, and plot it again, but this time double the height. The $y$ axis still goes from $0$ to $700$, but it takes twice as many pixels to do it. What happens to your histogram? It gets steeper. A log plot stretches the $y$-axis this way, but differently at different places, so at some points the graph gets steeper, and at some it gets less steep. Thus the shape changes, but the values involved are the same.